# Attach TimeStampToken (RFC5544) to signed PDF file

Tags: java, pdf, timestamp, itext

I would like to attach a timestamp to a PDF file previously signed with iText in Java (the input file extension is .pdf.p7m).
So I need to open an already signed PDF file and add a timestamp obtained from a TSA - Time Stamp Autority (I correctly obtain the TimeStampToken by using the TSAClientBouncyCastle class).
According to RFC 5955 [rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5955.txt](http://rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5955.txt) the resulting extension must be .tsd. So, when I bind the obtained timstamp to the signed PDF the resulting file will have the extension .pdf.p7m.tsa. But, How can I bind the TimeStampedData to the signed PDF?
I followed the http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures20130304.pdf white paper with no positive results.
Could anybody be so kind as to tell me how can I do it, please?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You say you want to **attach** a TST to a signed PDF. Do you want to attach using *integrated PDF signatures / timestamps according to ISO 32000-1, PAdES part 4, or ISO 32000-2*? Or do you want to attach using  *enveloping timestamps according to RFC 5544 and RFC 5955*? Your question header indicates  the latter while your question body seems to point towards the former. Those mechanisms are completely different.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I want to attach using enveloping timestamps according to **RFC 5544**, not ISO 32000-x. By following RFC5544 envelopment I will be ready to attach timestamp to CAdES as well. RFC 5544 is the best way for me becouse it describes how to apply RFC 3161 timestamps to data without signing them (the input file is already signed). Thank you once again.

Comment: In that case the white paper you referred to won't help you as it works along the lines of ISO 32000-* and PAdES.